# How to call a service method from another service method with "intent"?

Tags: java

I'm completely new to java. I've the following code in which I'm trying to retrieve a value from a database, but I need the value to be returned as a variable:

- The caller:

```
private String readInfo(String parameter, String option) {
        
        // some data conversion

        Context conVar = this;
        Intent intent = new Intent(conVar, FlipKRetriev.class);
        Log.d("LogMail", "Intent Create");
        //intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        Log.d("LogMail", "Add Flags");
        conVar.startService(intent);
        
        //no idea how to call FlipKRetriev.rgetData and return its variable
        
        Log.d("LogMail", "Start Intent");
        return "Missing Variable from FlipRetriev.rgetData";
    
    }
```

- The class and function that are getting called:

```
package com.flipkeyboard;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

public class FlipKRetriev extends Service {
    private FlipKDataBas jVarDB;

    @SuppressLint("Range")
    public CharSequence rgetData(String parameter, String options) {
            Log.d("LogMail", "Reached getData");

        jVarDB = new FlipKDataBas(this);

            int iConCCTS = jVarDB.conCCTS();

            Log.d("LogMail", String.valueOf(iConCCTS));
            Log.d("LogMail", "Called DB");
        
        // some data conversion...
        String varRet, varRet1, varRet2;
        return varRet;
    }
}
```

- And the method "conCCTS" within its "SQLLiteOpenHelper" call:

```
package com.flipkeyboard;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.DatabaseUtils;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class FlipKDataBas extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DBA_CCTS = "FlipKDB.db";
    public static final String TAB_CCTS = "CCTS";
    public static final String COL_ID = "ID";
    public static final String COL_NAME = "NAME";
    public static final String COL_EMAL = "EMAL";
    public static final String COL_PHWK = "PHWK";
    public static final String COL_PHMB = "PHMB";
    public static final String COL_CITY = "CITY";
    public static final String COL_CTRY = "CTRY";

    public FlipKDataBas(Context conVar) {
        super(conVar, DBA_CCTS, null, 1);
        Log.d("LogMail", "FlipKDataBas OK");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase varDB) {
        // some code...
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase varDB, int i, int i1) {
        // some code...
    }

    public int conCCTS() {
        SQLiteDatabase varDB = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Log.d("LogMail", "Count DB");
        return (int) DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(varDB, TAB_CCTS);
    }
}
```

The problem is that I've no idea on how to call the method "rgetData" from the "intent" I'm using in "readInfo".

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this with a workaround:

This basically changes the "intent" method for a more specific series of calls to the FlipKRetriev class.

```
        // This is to fetch the information from the database
        FlipKRetriev cls = new FlipKRetriev();
            Context conVar = this;

            cls.parameter = txtPar;
            cls.options = option;
            cls.rStartSrv(conVar);
            retValFKR = cls.rgetData();
```

Where:

- parameter/options are variables that I send to the new class.
- retValFKR is the expected return from the initial class that I'm assigning the results to.

The error that I was getting was that I was not passing the Context from the first class to the second one (I was using "this" directly in the second class), which is needed to be able to link them.

```
    public void rStartSrv(Context context) {
        //parameter = (String) intent.getExtras().get("parameter");
        //options = (String) intent.getExtras().get("options");
        Log.d("LogMail", "Reached On Receive");
        jVarDB = new FlipKDataBas(context);
        int iConCCTS = jVarDB.conCCTS();
        Log.d("LogMail", String.valueOf(iConCCTS));
        Log.d("LogMail", String.valueOf(parameter));
        Log.d("LogMail", String.valueOf(options));
    }
```

Without the context, the database variables were unable to be called.